# Cloud SQL connection failed from a cloud run

Tags: node.js, postgresql, google-cloud-sql

We have our running staging env running over a micro services based on Cloud Run and SQL database running postgreSQL.

Everything is working fine for weeks and suddenly this morning, 2 of our microservice can't connect to SQL instances with such error:
`Cloud SQL connection failed`. Please see https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-overview for additional details:

```
Post "https://sqladmin.googleapis.com/sql/v1beta4/projects/rebalance-backend/instances/xxxxxxx/createEphemeral?alt=json&prettyPrint=false": connection to Cloud SQL Admin API at sqladmin.googleapis.com:443 as 459280809529-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com failed: connect tcp [2a00:1450:400c:c06::5f]:443: connection was refused.
```

We have searched a long time any setting issue without result.

Any hints or help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Philippe

Comment: Has this been resolved? Today there was an incident which caused some Networking issues and it could be that you were affected  by that. You can check the information about the incident in the following [link](https://status.cloud.google.com/incidents/1xkAB1KmLrh5g3v9ZEZ7).

Comment: We have restarted the instance by adding a flag and it runs fine now.
I am not sure the incident you mentioned is related but could be anyhow.
Thx